# Regex pattern match string irrespective of order

Tags: regex

I have a comma-separated string and wanted to check if the string has all words irrespective of order using REGEX pattern.

Example: Original String = "help, assist, aid";

Use Cases:

1. "help, assist, aid" -> return true
2. "aid, assist, help" -> return true
3. "aid, help,assist" -> return true
4. "aid, help" -> return false
5. "aid, help,support" -> return false

Can someone help me in writing the regex pattern for this use case?

Comment: What should "aid, help, support, assist" return? In other words, should it consist of _just_ those three words?

Answer (score 1):

You could use three positive lookahead assertions:

```
^(?=.*\bhelp\b)(?=.*\baid\b)(?=.*\bassist\b).*$
```

Each of the three lookaheads is actually zero width, and so would all be evaluated once at the very start of the pattern.

### Demo

Comment: in case words other than these not allowed, negative lookahead assertion `(?!.*\b(?!(help|assist|aid)\b)\w)` may be added